# If $x$, $y$ and $z$ satisfy $xy=1$, $yz=2$ and $xz=3$, what is the value of $x^2+y^2+z^2$? Express your answer as a common fraction.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> If $x$, $y$ and $z$ satisfy $xy=1$, $yz=2$ and $xz=3$, what is the value of $x^2+y^2+z^2$?  Express your answer as a common fraction.

---

I tried going along the path of computing $(x+y+z)^2$, which expands to $(x^2+y^2+z^2) + 2\cdot (xy+yz+xz)$, but I couldn't go anywhere from there (other than substituting xy, yz, xz, but that's not enough information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Calculate $${(xy)(yz)\over xz}$$

Comment: is the denominator correct?

Comment: I think this particular combination would give the value of $y^2$. Computing the others and then adding, we get the answer to be: $\frac{1\cdot2}{3}+\frac{2\cdot3}{1}+\frac{3\cdot1}{2}=49/6.$ Is that correct?

Comment: yes..............

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** $$(xy)(yz)(xz)=(xyz)^2,$$
take square root, then divide by $xy$ or $yz$ or $xz$ to find $z,\,x,\,y$ respectively.

Comment: Oh wow, I thought of what you did, but for some reason, I didn't see the connection between divide xyz by xy, etc.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT.** You can take the equations pairwise. For example, you have $xy=1$ and $yz=2$. So for example,
$$
\dfrac{1}{2}= \dfrac{xy}{yz}=\dfrac{x}{z}
$$
But then $z=2x$. But you know $xz=3$. Can you substitute and find $x$ or $z$? Can you repeat this process for $y$? Knowing their values it should be routine to find $x^2+y^2+z^2$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\text{Compilation of all *Hints*}$$

We know that $$(x+y+z)=xyz(\frac{1}{xy}+\frac{1}{yz}+\frac{1}{zx})$$
From here we see that $$(x+y+z)=xyz(\frac{11}{6})$$

Also, $(xyz)^2=6$ , so it would be nice to say that
$$(x+y+z)^2=6\big(\frac{11}{6}\big)^2$$

Then write the expansion for $$(x+y+z)^2$$ and keep substituting till you get the answer.